# Remove noise from magnetometer data

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, magnetometer

I want to use data from a **magnetometer** to gain information about the motion of a metal object near it. After recording the data, I need to remove noise from the data before using it. What is a good method to remove noise? I read about filters in Matlab [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/signal-smoothing.html?prodcode=SG&language=en) but cannot decide which one to use. How can I decide which filter to use?

Edit:
The metal object moves at a steady rate and I want to find out the angle of its motion. I am adding a graph from my sample data which I want to filter. [Sample Magnetometer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtq38.png)

Comment: This depends entirely on how your signal looks, and how you *want* it to look. What frequencies are you interested in? Can you say that the metal object only moves slowly, or can it make large jumps? Please edit your question to include such information, and (if possible) please share either the data, or upload a plot of the data.

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're able to record the noise. And if you can do it, yo can also use some adaptive filtering.

From [MathWorks' Overview of Adaptive Filters and Applications](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/overview-of-adaptive-filters-and-applications.html):

> Block Diagram That Defines the Inputs and Output of a Generic RLS Adaptive Filter
> [image]

You can use recorded noise as **desired signal** and your **error signal** should be around 0 without any motion near it, and should have some filtered value when the motion appears.

You can find an [example of adaptive filtering on the MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/adaptive-neural-network-filters.html#bss4gqu-8):

> Consider a pilot in an airplane. When the pilot speaks into a microphone, the engine noise in the cockpit combines with the voice signal. This additional noise makes the resultant signal heard by passengers of low quality. The goal is to obtain a signal that contains the pilot's voice, but not the engine noise. You can cancel the noise with an adaptive filter if you obtain a sample of the engine noise and apply it as the input to the adaptive filter.
>
> [image]

Read more about adaptive filtering:

- Overview: http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/overview-of-adaptive-filters-and-applications.html
- NN adaptive filters: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/adaptive-neural-network-filters.html